# Pydantic Error while importing Trulens eval

Tags: pydantic

I'm following along with the DLAI Building and Evaluating Advanced RAG videos. Where one gets to try LLama index + Trulens for evaluating a RAG.

The Llama index works after some adjustments due to depreciation, but trulens doesn't even import. I get the following error when trying:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PydanticUserError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 1
----> 1 from trulens_eval import Tru
      2 tru = Tru()
      4 tru.reset_database()

File c:\Users\Dator\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\__init__.py:38
     36 from trulens_eval.schema import FeedbackMode
     37 from trulens_eval.schema import Query
---> 38 from trulens_eval.tru import Tru
     39 from trulens_eval.tru_chain import TruChain
     40 from trulens_eval.tru_feedback import Feedback

File c:\Users\Dator\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\tru.py:18
     16 from trulens_eval.schema import App
     17 from trulens_eval.schema import Record
---> 18 from trulens_eval.tru_db import JSON
     19 from trulens_eval.tru_db import LocalSQLite
     20 from trulens_eval.tru_feedback import Feedback

File c:\Users\Dator\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\trulens_eval\tru_db.py:130
    122         """
    123         Get the records logged for the given set of `app_ids` (otherwise all)
    124         alongside the names of the feedback function columns listed the
...
    399     ):

PydanticUserError: A non-annotated attribute was detected: `TABLE_META = 'meta'`. All model fields require a type annotation; if `TABLE_META` is not meant to be a field, you may be able to resolve this error by annotating it as a `ClassVar` or updating `model_config['ignored_types']`.
```

This question is similar to the one in stackoverflow.com/questions/77599781/error-while-importing-trueera-trulens-eval, but I am not allowed to comment as i have too few credits here, and I have understood that I shouldn't pose a question as an answer.

I have tried to install and uninstall the following versions of pydantic 2.6.3, 1.10.14 and 1.10.13 and i have also tried installing typing-extensions-4.5.0. Is there something else that I have to install in a different version to make this work?